# How to use localDb with entity framework migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, localdb

I have `Persistence` class library, which contains my `DbContext` class. It also contains app.config file, where I have predefined connection string like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="<Namespace1>.Persistence.AssessmentContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AssessmentContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Assuming that AssesmentContext has `Namespace1.Persistence` namespace.

When I try to enable-migrations using PM console, it gives me such an error:

```
An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file.
```

When I tried to debug it and put debug output into AssessmentContext ctor I found that the connection string is still using .\SQLEXPRESS data source.

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=<Namespace1>.Persistence.AssessmentContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

So what I am doing wrong? And why EF doesn't take my connection string from app.config?

Comment: Are you using your `DbContext` outside of your class library or only within your class library?

Comment: Do you have SQL 2014 installed?

Comment: No SQL 2014 installed. yes, I am using DbContext outside of my class library through repositories.

Comment: So which connection string do you have defined in the project where you are instantiating the `DBContext`

Comment: I do not instantiating anything right now, what I want is to enable migrations and update the database with initial values.

Comment: Did you try to specify the connection string name like: `Update-Database -ConnectionStringName "<Namespace1>.Persistence.AssessmentContext"`

Answer (score 0):

The above connection string entry must be copied to the app.config of the executable program if you are using desktop app or copied to web.config if you are using web app.